# Every identity arrow is iso

Tags: category-theory

> Every identity arrow is iso.

I struggling a bit with this proof,
can someone help?

I understand that isomorphic is invertible and for a function $f:a\to b$ is invertible if there exists a function $g:b\to a$ s.t. $g\circ f=1_a$ and $f\circ g=1_b$.

Comment: Does the question read: "Prove that every identity map is an isomorphism" ?

Comment: It does read that

Comment: You just had such a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3561065/example-of-a-function-that-is-not-injective), is it really category theory what you need?

Comment: Category theory is what I need, but my task is to understand topics in category theory and then give examples through set theory terms also.

Comment: I don't recall much of the subject, but the inverse is clearly the identity map itself and everything is mapped to itself (objects and functors)...

Comment: I know its simple, but I was just wondering what the proof would look like. I didn't know if it was enough to say that the inverse is the identity map itself, and then composing the identity function with the identity function would give the identity by definition of isos.

Comment: Yes, it is enough, since it satisfies the definition (with inverse itself).

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an identity arrow $1_x$ for some object $x$. By definition, $1_x: x\to x$ and for every $f:y\to x$ and every $g:x\to z$, we have $1_x\circ f=f$ and $g\circ 1_x=g$; in particular, then, with $f=g=1_x$, we have $1_x\circ 1_x=1_x$. Can you continue from here?

*Hint:*

> Prove uniqueness of inverses.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate this!

Comment: You're welcome, @Asuna!